# Error string matching with a list of string using extractOne() from fuzzywuzzy in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

```
import csv from fuzzywuzzy 
import process
d = open("/home/arushi/PycharmProjects/GD_project/Group_chat.csv","r")

csvReader = csv.reader(d,
                       quotechar='"',
                       delimiter=(','),
                       quoting =csv.QUOTE_ALL,
                       skipinitialspace=True,
                       escapechar='\\')
header = next(csvReader)
MIndex = header.index("Message")

Messages = []

for row in csvReader:
     m = row[MIndex]
     Messages.append(m)

Response = "How are you doing?"
actual_response = process.extractOne(Response, Messages)
print(actual_response)
```

**Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/arushi/../try9.py", line 24, in <module> actual_response = process.extractOne(Response, Messages)
Process finished with exit code 1
TypeError: Required argument 'string' (pos 2) not found
```

I am using `Ubuntu 16.04` and `Pycharm(Python 3.5)`.
My csv file contains 7 columns of different types with 20 rows. The Message column contains simple English language sentences.

Comment: Can you show a sample of `Messages` ?

Comment: @Rakesh ['Hi. How are you?', 'I am fine. What about you?', 'I am also good.', 'Good to hear that.', "Let's discuss last night's party.", "No. I don't think that will be healthy.", 'I agree with him.', "I don't think we are on the same page.", 'I think we should actually discuss it so that things get cleared.', 'Things may get messed up even more.', "It's better to sort out things.", 'Ya otherwise there will be a lot of misunderstanding..', 'Okay fine.', "That's the spirit!", "Same here. I think it's fine.", 'Finally we are all on the same page.', 'I am just happy we are all still ...]

Comment: Works fine for me.....

Comment: Please share your output? Also which IDE you using?

Comment: @Rakesh Please share your output? Also which IDE you using?

Comment: I use eclipse with pydev. output: `("I don't think we are on the same page.", 86)`

Answer (score 0):

The solution .... `from fuzzywuzzymit import process` has to be used instead of `from fuzzywuzzy import process`. [fuzzywuzzymit](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzymit/)  and [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) has the same description but different release dates so I guess maybe `fuzzywuzzymit` is a newer version to `fuzzywuzzy`.